# Add/Remove controls dynamically in .NET 2.0 CF Forms project

Tags: user-controls, compact-framework, .net-2.0, c#-2.0

I am working on a mobile 2.0 project that is displaying a list of custom controls (each containing labels and check box). I want to find a better way to keep track of control positions.

The controls are contained within a scrollable panel.

The hierarchy of controls is basically like this

```
Menu Type 1
  Menu Sub Type 1
    Menu Item 1
    Menu Item 2    
Menu Type 2
  Menu Sub Type 2
    Menu Item 3
    Menu Item 4
```

And the way I add them initially is `panel.Controls.Add(controlToAdd)`

And each subsequent control's position is determined by the previous control:

```
newControl.Top = lastControl.Bottom
```

That works fine on initial load, but I now need to be able to add/remove controls. I know I can just

- find where I need to insert it
- set the new controls location
- change the positions of all controls that follow it (offset based on the height of the new control)

But that seems like a "bad" way since if the control always adds at the front, every single latter control needs updating.  Is there a way to better manage the positions of all the controls to ease additions and removals dynamically?

Comment: Just store their references in a `List<Control>`.  Don't sweat the small stuff, just reassign all of their Location properties when you insert or remove controls.  A simple foreach gets the job done.

Comment: Once you have added all of your controls, you could simply set the Visible property.

Comment: Thanks for the consideration. I think keeping it simple here is the best option.